# Add x meter UTM coordinate system

Tags: gps, utm

I have lat and lng I convert this in UTM coordinate system, I would like to add x meter in this UTM system, what is the best way ? 
For example I have this UTM system and I want to move this system 2 meters Noth-East direction:

[East] => 340337.35
 
 [North] => 5307320.905
 [UTMZone] => 32T

Comment: Please include the software you have available to work with

Comment: I work with PHP an JS. I use this code to covert GPS coordinate to UTM https://gist.github.com/duedal/840476 @ Bjorn

Comment: Split the 2 m offset into its North and East components and add (I think) to the false easting and false northing values. The existing false northing is zero.